# Нужно увидеть в папке сеть пользователей из другой подсети по протоколу SMB

Tags: windows, active-directory, smb

Есть домен site.local и 2 офиса в единой локальной сети

1 сеть : 
192.168.1.0/24
шлюз 192.168.1.1

2 сеть :
192.168.10.0/24
шлюз 192.168.1.1

Все машины заведены домен и на
на всех ПК работает SMB протокол ,который добавляли по этой [инструкции](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2696547/detect-enable-disable-smbv1-smbv2-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows-server)

Но есть проблема,ПК из одной подсети не могут посмотреть ПК из другой подсети в сетевой папке **Сеть(Network)** ,но могут попасть на них,если пропишут имя нужной машины из другой подсети.( \\solovey)

Вопрос заключается в том,как организовать видимость машин другой подсети?

Comment: Или поднять WINS-сервер, или домен...

Comment: Нужно чтобы мастер-браузер был един для всех сетей (это сервис "Браузер компьютеров"/"Browser").